# Will changing the order of Channel Images categories screw anything up?

Tags: channel-images

I've set up a "Channel Images" field that has a comma-separated list of categories. The client wants to modify the order of that list. If I change the order of those categories, will that mess anything up? Will any existing category assignments be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used channel images but technically speaking, changing order of categories is purely a visual order, EE refers categories internally by ID.

Simply changing an order does not generally affect anything assigned to it.

Comment: However, in "Channel Images," the categories list is a single text string, with categories separated by commas. So my question remains: if I modify that list -- by rearranging or renaming the categories, or deleting categories -- will that screw up any existing category assignments?

Comment: Are the categories EE category IDs or ChannelImages category IDs?

Comment: Channel Images.